# How do i set the guild's name in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to set the guild's name.
This is what I tried:
`ctx.guild.name = "test"`

Comment: Hi @3hdream, welcome to Stack Overflow. Asking a good question can be difficult. Please read this post [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some ways that you may be able to improve you question so people can answer it well.

Comment: At least one thing that comes to mind is that you may want to include all relevant code that you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fuction you're looking for is `guild.edit()`. See the following link for documentation:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.edit

I believe the proper usage would be `ctx.guild.edit(**{"name":"New Name"})` or `ctx.guild.edit(name="New Name")`.

Comment: to expand on this, discord object properties are **read only**, this is why you need to use this roundabout way

Comment: Thanks, it helped me!